# Insert smarty variable into sass

Tags: css, variables, sass, smarty

Can I insert smarty variable like example `<{$BG_COLOR}>` into a scss file?

I need think like this:

```
$color1:#<{$BG_COLOR}>;
```

Thanks

Comment: `<{&BG_COLOR}>` doesn't look anything like Smarty to me

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so :

```
$font: {$myFont};
$textColour: {$myTextColour};
$background: {$myBackground};
```

Source :

https://www.neontribe.co.uk/smart-sass-dynamic-sass-variables-with-php-smarty/